# Best way to make iPhone CoreLocation call on a separate thread?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, asynchronous, core-location

Is there a way to fire off a thread to call CoreLocation a few times, which will then update the UI whenever it gets around to getting a position of a certain accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't need a separate thread. In you `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, your `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method is called for every CL update. Check the accuracy (and possible the timestamp) and update your UI accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but here's the deal - I want to get the location when I take a photo, store it to a database, and use it to get weather info. The weather info getter uses NSXMLParser, so I just fire that off and then use parserDidEndDocument to fire a row updater when it finishes parsing. So what I want is to do something similar with coreLocation - fire off a CL process, then when it gets the location to a sufficient accuracy or when it times out, store the data then fire off the weather code. I'd like all this to happen asynchronously.

Comment: Oh wait, I've just been reading the documentation a little more closely. I've been using cllocation as if it were a synchronous call, and didn't understand that it does just what you said, and you can receive updates with didUpdateToLocation. So it looks like I can do everything as I just described.